# UserTransaction.SetTransactionTimeout not working?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, timeout, wildfly

In the following code I am trying to force a transaction timeout for a specific bean setting its transaction time shorter than the time it takes for the method to complete.

The timeout is set for **3 seconds**, and the time it takes for the method to complete is **5 seconds**.

I am using a portable solution which refers to a combination of BMT and setting the timeout with the [`setTransactionTimeout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/transaction/TransactionManager.html#setTransactionTimeout(int)) method.

I would expect the transaction to be invalidated an throw me an Exception, but that is not happening.

What am I doing wrong?

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class TimerSingleton {

    @Inject
    private UserTransaction ut;

    @PostConstruct
    public void execute() throws Exception {

        ut.begin();
        ut.setTransactionTimeout(3); // Transaction should timeout after 3 seconds

        System.out.println(">>> Executing...");
        Thread.sleep(5000); // Block for 5 seconds

        ut.commit();

        System.out.println(">>> Completed");
    }
}
```

The method is completely executed:

```
17:00:12,138 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) >>> Executing...

17:00:17,139 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) >>> Completed
```

I am using Wildfly 8.2 and I know about the `@TransactionTimeout` annotation, but it is proprietary and I would like to know how to control it in a portable manner.

Comment: try switching `ut.begin();` and `ut.setTransactionTimeout(3);`

Comment: @FedericoSierra It worked! I tried that early today but I might had misunderstood the exception! Can you please post an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `setTransactionTimeout` method must invoked before you call `begin` method, this is because `setTransactionTimeout` modify the timeout value that is associated with transactions started by the current thread with the `begin` method.

Comment: Setting the transaction timeout before beginning the transaction fixed my code, thank you.