# disable arjuna transaction timeout

Tags: wildfly

Although I've called `UserTransaction.setTransactionTimeout()`, the transaction has been canceled after 5 minutes (default arjuna transaction timeout). How can I disable the arjuna transaction timeout in order to manage the transaction timeout through `UserTransaction.setTransactionTimeout()`?

I'm using Wildfly 8.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28096898/usertransaction-settransactiontimeout-not-working. Could you check answer to that problem?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I've discovered that it was another transaction (I have a transaction chaining) that has been aborted. I've get the problem resolved by using NOT_SUPPORTED transaction attribute on them caller bean methods.